# POI - Excel remains held by some process and cannot be edited

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using POI to read,edit and write excel files.
My process flow is like write an excel, read it and again write it.

Then if I try to edit the file using normal desktop excel application while my Java app is still running, the excel cannot be saved, it says some process is holding the excel,
I am properly closing all file handles.

Please help and tell me how to fix this issue.

```
SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(WINDOW_SIZE);
Sheet sheet = getCurrentSheet();//stores the current sheet in a instance variable
for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < data.size(); rowNum++) {
    if (rowNum > RECORDS_PER_SHEET) {
        if (rowNum % (RECORDS_PER_SHEET * numberOfSheets) == 1) {
            numberOfSheets++;
            setCurrentSheet(wb.getXSSFWorkbook().createSheet());
            sheet = getCurrentSheet();
        }
    }
    final Row row = sheet.createRow(effectiveRowCnt);
    for (int columnCount = 0; columnCount < data.get(rowNum).size(); columnCount++) {
        final Object value = data.get(rowNum).get(columnCount);
        final Cell cell = row.createCell(columnCount);
        //This method creates the row and cell at the given loc and adds value
        createContent(value, cell, effectiveRowCnt, columnCount, false, false);
    }
}

public void closeFile(boolean toOpen) {
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(getFileName());
        wb.write(out);            
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
                out = null;
                if(toOpen){
                    // Open the file for user with default program
                    final Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
                    dt.open(new File(getFileName()));
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: After a bit of testing I suppose my output stream/ some other handle is taking some time to close. As, even if my Java app keeps running if I try after some time I am able to edit and save the file.

Comment: So now how do I make sure my streams have closed properly?

Comment: Show us some code!  Without knowing what you're currently doing, we can't help fix your issues!

Comment: The code is huge and does a lot of complicated logic on data.
Basically, the code uses SXSSFWorkbook and Sheet apis from POI

First I write some data to the excel. I close the FileOutputStream.

Next I read the same excel, do some data manipulation and write to the same excel.

Now when I open the excel in MS Excel and try to manipulate some data or remove some and save it says the excel is in  use.

Comment: Is it possible because of the Event User model, as if I use the XSSFWorkbook, the problem does not seem to appear.

When I am using XSSFReader with SharedStringsTable, the problem happens.

Comment: Share the code for writing.

Comment: added the writing code

Comment: Unrelated to your question, since you're using the `SXSSF` format, you  _must_ manually clean up any temp files that the format creates by calling `wb.dispose()` (as documented [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf))

Comment: I am using POI 3.8 and the method dispose() is not recognised.

Answer (score 2):

The code looks correct. After `out.close();`, there shouldn't be any locks left.

Things that could still happen:

1. You have another Java process (for example hanging in a debugger). Your new process tries to write the file, fails (because of process 1) and in the `finally`, it tries to open Excel which sees the same problem. Make sure you log all exceptions that happen in `wb.write(out);`

   Note: The code above looks correct in this respect, since it only starts Excel when `out != null` and that should only be the case when Java could open the file.
2. Maybe the file wasn't written completely (i.e. there was an exception during `write()`). Excel tries to open the corrupt file and gives you the wrong error message.
3. Use a tool like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to find out which process keeps a lock on a file.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I would check the above possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the options. After looking thoroughly, it seems the problem is the Event User model.
I am using the below code for reading the data:

```
    final OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(getFileName());
    final XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader(pkg);
    final SharedStringsTable sst = r.getSharedStringsTable();

    final XMLReader parser = fetchSheetParser(sst);

    final Iterator<InputStream> sheets = r.getSheetsData();

    while (sheets.hasNext()) {
        final InputStream sheet = sheets.next();
        final InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheet);
        parser.parse(sheetSource);
        sheet.close();
    }
```

I assume the excel is for some reason held by this process for some time. If I remove this code and use the below code:

```
    final File file = new File(getFileName());
    final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    final XSSFWorkbook xWb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
```

The process works fine an the excel does not remain locked.

Comment: You don't appear to be closing the package object at the end, could it be as simple as that?

Comment: @Gagravarr: Yes as simple as that, I figured that out an I already posted the solution. The Apache documentation for POI actually is bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out actually.
A very simple line was required but some some reason it was not explained in the New Halloween Document (http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf)

I checked the Busy Developer's Guide and got the solution.
I needed to add

pkg.close(); //To close the OPCPackage

This added my code works fine with any number of reads and writes on the same excel file.